# How can I shuffle a folder of music without interupting or pausing other code in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, macos-mojave

In short I would like to shuffle a folder of .mp3 files in the background so I can still have a program running. I on Mac OS X. I have managed to get all the files in a list using `Glob` and I can then play them with the playsound plugin [found here.](https://pypi.org/project/playsound/) However this script prevents anything else from running until all the songs are finished with isn't what I want. I tried `pygame` with this code... `pip install pygame` (Which worked successfully), and then...

```
import pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
pygame.mixer.music.load("file.mp3")
pygame.mixer.music.play()
```

This however always returns the same error, `pygame.error: MPEG file does not have any audio stream.` So I have the files in a list but no way to play them in the background. Can someone help with this please?

UPDATE ON CODE:

I actually managed to get it to play sounds with this code bellow...

```
import time
import glob
import pygame

pygame.mixer.init()
def play_my_mix(data = "error"):
    for file in glob.glob("data/music/mix/*.mp3"):
        pygame.mixer.music.load(file)
        pygame.mixer.music.play()

print("test")
play_my_mix()
print("apple")
time.sleep(15)
```

However the audio is in awful quality. It sounds sort of warped and slow. The `time.sleep(15)` line is there to keep the program running because otherwise it just stops which is ok considering this is a test. I did however change that to this...

```
x = 1
while x == 1:
    print("good")
```

In case it was something to do with the time but it didn't change it at all.

Comment: Might need to look into [Asynchronous Python using `asyncio`](https://realpython.com/async-io-python/). Either that or find out if either `pygame` or `playsound` have async methods you can call instead of the synchronous methods you've been using.

Comment: `pygame` plays music asynchronously by default (otherwise the music will freeze the game). I don't know why it gives you that error though. pygame is known to have some issues on MacOS, could be related to that, not sure

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll look into the `asyncio` methods.

Comment: I have looked into the `asyncio` methods but can't work out how to set it up for the task I would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I fixed the first part with the update code as mentioned in the edit. The second problem with the audio lag I fixed by changing `pygame.mixer.init()` to `pygame.mixer.init(44100, -16, 2, 2048)`